# Is there a known issue with memory leaks in Python dicts or Numpy iterators?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks, gdal

A function that iterates over a large Numpy array using nd.iter is consuming far more memory that expected.

I have a large (~120mb) image containing class values (each a uint8 between 0 and 9). For each class, I'd like to build a list of indicies that can be used for further operations, like so:

```py
class_dict = {
    1:[(2,3),(2,4),(2,5).....],   # Pixels containing class 1
    2:[(30000,2333),(54444,23232) .....],    # Pixels containing class 2
    ....
}
```

At present, this is produced by the following code:

```py
class = gdal.Open("path/to/class/geotiff")
class_array = gdal.GetVirtualMemArray()  # shape=(11027,10954)

def build_class_dict(class_array, no_data=None):
    """Returns a dict of coordinates of the following shape:
    [class, coord_list]"""
    out_dict = {}
    it = np.nditer(class_array, flags=['multi_index'])
    while not it.finished:
        this_class = int(it.value)
        if this_class == no_data:
            it.iternext()
            continue
        if this_class in out_dict.keys():
            out_dict[this_class].append(it.multi_index)
        else:
            out_dict.update({this_class: [it.multi_index]})
        it.iternext()
    return out_dict
```

Given that I'm essentially storing the entire image again twice, I'd expect the memory footprint of that function to grow by quite a bit - say to about ~3gb, accounting for the usual Python overhead, which is not a problem.

What is happening is that the footprint of the program grows very quickly to fill all available space. It completes in about a minute for images with a lot (~80%) of nodata values, but for anything else it will starve the machine of resources and lock up.

Is there a problem, memory-wise, with this implementation, or will I have to rethink? Environment is Python 3.6.7, numpy 1.15.4 (but tried on 1.16.4), gdal 2.4.1, running on ubuntu 18.02.

**EDIT**
A further development; when profiling the function with @memory_profiler.profile decorator, memory jumps and then holds steady - which is what I expected. This is not how it behaved when unmonitored, but it is also running far slower.

Answer (score 0):

So the source array is shape `(11027,10954)` and `uint8` dtype.  It's memory use is roughly 120789758 bytes - one byte per pixel.

Ignoring the `nodata` for the moment, dictionary contains the same number of tuples, each with two integers (4 or 8 bytes each), split among 10 lists. That's 3*120789758 pointers.  A much higher memory usage.  That's not a leak, just a data structure that requires a lot of memory.

I generally discourage the use of `nditer` in Python code, since it does not provide any speed advantage over plain iteration.  But since you are using it for the multiindex it's probably not a bad choice.

Your dictionary use looks a lot like `collections.defaultdict`.  That could shorten your code, though not change memory use or speed.

If `nodata` was 0, you could also put this image in a `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix` - except there the dictionary keys are the index tuples themselves, and dictionary values the pixel values.